# Regex : obtener partes de una cadena

Tags: php, array, regex

Tengo la siguiente cadena **[id:123] [nombre:Luis] [pais:Mexico]** y lo que busco es convertirlo en un array para que quede algo así.

```
array {
  "id" => "123"
  "nombre" => "Luis"
  "pais" => "Mexico"
}
```

Trate con la expresión regular:

```
\[([^\[\]]*:[^\[\]]*)\]
```

y la función **preg_match_all()** de php pero no logro conseguirlo.
https://regex101.com/r/ZuPzug/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con todo respeto, difiero de la sugerencia de @phpMyGuel de que se prescinda de la expresión regular para casos como estos. Por el motivo de que un simple espacio de más o de menos tumbaría el código. Es muy fácil que a cualquiera se le escape un espacio. El código tampoco funcionaría como se espera si hay nombres compuestos como `Luis José` o `Costa Rica`, etc.

Entonces, lo más seguro es:

- Extraer las cadenas que están entre `[]` usando una expresión regular
- Trabajar con ese `match` para crear el nuevo array, aplicando `trim` tanto a las claves como a los valores

Con esas dos cosas el código quedaría blindado contra posibles cadenas descontroladas en cuanto a espacios.

La función quedaría así:

```
function stringToAssoc($str){
    #Extraemos todo lo que haya entre "[]"
    preg_match_all('#\[(.*?)\]#', $str, $matches);
    #El array final
    $array=[];
    foreach ($matches[1] as $pair) {
        #Separamos por el delimitador :
        $b = explode(':', $pair);
        #1er dato del array como clave, 2º dato como valor. 
        #Aplicamos trim para limpiar posibles espacios
        $array[trim($b[0])] = trim($b[1]);
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Ahora hagamos dos pruebas, una con tu cadena original y la otra con una cadena un poco loca, porque ese día el programador estaba pendiente del WhatsAppppp :)

```
#Caso original
$str="[id:123] [nombre:Luis] [pais:Mexico]";
var_dump(stringToAssoc($str));
```

**Salida:**

```
array(3) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(3) "123"
  ["nombre"]=>
  string(4) "Luis"
  ["pais"]=>
  string(6) "Mexico"
}
```

---

```
#Caso WhatsApp :-)
$str="  [id: 123] [nombre:Luis José]    [pais: Costa Rica   ]   ";
var_dump(stringToAssoc($str));
```

**Salida:**

```
array(3) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(3) "123"
  ["nombre"]=>
  string(10) "Luis José"
  ["pais"]=>
  string(10) "Costa Rica"
}
```

Comment: La pregunta es dada una cadena determinada se ha de transformar a un **array asociativo**. No me meto en el escenario puesto que no lo conocemos, podría imaginarme que la cadena viene saneada ya por otro procedimiento o que se consigue directamente de unos campos de un formulario, puestos a imaginar podría encajar con muchos escenarios muy diferentes. En cualquier caso me gusta responder sin basarme en supociones, trabajando con lo que el OP aporta. Así quizás en futuras preguntas se construya un escenario más preciso.

Comment: @phpMyGuel con un simple espacio en cualquier parte tu código se rompe. Yo creo que aunque se suponga que los datos vienen saneados, hay que establecer controles también a nivel de PHP para evitar sorpresas. Es más, **tu código se rompe en cuanto haya un nombre compuesto** como `Luis José` por ejemplo. O sea, el problema va más allá de sanear o no sanear.

Comment: Si no te quito la razón. De hecho empecé a programarlo con expresiones regulares, incluso contemplando el tipo de los datos para que dada la cadena `["id":123] ["nombre":"Luis"] ["pais":"Mexico"]` devolviese lo que tenía que devolver, pero como dije, no me quise meter a imaginarme escenarios teóricos.

Comment: @phpMyGuel no son *escenarios teóricos*. Como comprenderás, hay un país que se llama `Costa Rica` y otro que se llama `Puerto Rico` y otro que se llama `República Democrática del Congo`. Cuando en los datos haya cualquiera de esos países el código de tu respuesta no arroja los resultados esperados. A no ser que el OP haya dicho: *necesito esto para un contexto en el que **siempre** los datos no tendrán más de una palabra*. Aún así, yo establecería controles por lo mismo que digo en la respuesta, porque muchos usuarios mientras trabajan están pendiente de otras cosas y se escapan espacios, etc.

Comment: Si no te quito la razón, te lo digo de nuevo. Si la función fuese para mí contemplaría ese caso. O quizás evitaría los espacios entre palabras por guiones bajos, o lo tendría en un JSON o muchos otros "oes". Pero personalmente desarrollo mis respuestas en base a lo que entrega el OP y así de paso lo mismo consigo una pregunta mejor trabajada que contemple un escenario mejor definido, como también ya he dicho.

Comment: Evitemos las referencias a otras respuestas, salvo que sean referencias positivas por favor. Gracias!

Comment: Lamento no haber dado mas información.
Efectivamente antes de poder trabajar con la cadena la saneo, no mostré todo el proceso por el que pasa la cadena ya que solo me interesaba el hecho de convertirlo a un array y sobre las respuestas que dieran adaptarlas a lo que buscaba. Realmente no esperaba que hicieran todo el trabajo y por eso fue que no puse una descripción mas detallada de lo que buscaba, una disculpa. Solo buscaba ideas para resolver dicho problema.

Answer (score 1):

En tu caso concreto puedes ahorrarte la expresión regular. En la cadena de ejemplo el separador de elementos es el espacio. Sabiendo esto podemos usar la función `explode()` para crear un **array** a partir de dicha cadena.

¿Cuál es el problema? Que con dicha función conseguimos un **array** con índice numérico y no un **array asociativo** con **string** de índices.

Por ello cree una función que recibe este **array** y devuelve uno **asociativo**.

```
$cadena = '[id:123] [nombre:Luis] [pais:Mexico]';
$valores_reemplazar = array("[", "]");
$cadena = str_replace($valores_reemplazar, "", $cadena);
$cadena_troceada = explode(" ", $cadena);

$asociativo = transforma_a_asociativo ($cadena_troceada);

var_dump($asociativo);

function transforma_a_asociativo ($array) {
    $array_respuesta = NULL;

    foreach ($array as $fila) {
        $trozos = explode(':', $fila);
        $clave = $trozos[0];
        $valor = $trozos[1];

        $array_respuesta[$clave] = $valor;
    }

    return $array_respuesta;
}
```

El código devolvería:

```
array(3) { ["id"]=> string(3) "123" ["nombre"]=> string(4) "Luis" ["pais"]=> string(6) "Mexico" }
```

Comment: En cuanto haya un nombre compuesto como `Luis José` o `María Antonia` este código no resuelve el problema.